# Transform a collect_list column to other data type column using UDF in spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

The request is to union data from 2 streaming sources, and then reduce on the same key, and apply a function for the values to transform it to another UDO (user defined object type). I have no idea how to do it. So here I just created a similar problem as below:

The 2 input streams have 3 columns, id, value and posttime. We first union it, and then reduce based on id and produce the final result with values (id, user-defined-function(values, posttimes)). How to achieve this?

If I implement it as follows:

```
val dff = df.union(df2)
  .withWatermark("posttime", "15 minutes")
  .groupBy(window($"posttime", "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),$"id")
  .agg(collect_list(struct("value", "posttime")).as("data"))
  .withColumn("data", user-defined-function("data"))
```

How should I define the user-defined-function to input the column and output a column with different data type?

```
// How to tranform the Column (Type: A) to output Column (Type: B)
def user-defined-function(columnName: String): Column = {
  val x = Column(columnName).cast(List<struct>)
  val ptime = if(x.posttime < y.posttime) x.posttime else y.posttime
  val value = (x.value.toInt + y.value.toInt).toString
  return new Column(struct(value, ptime))
}
```

Comment: `if(x.posttime < y.posttime) x.posttime else y.posttime` can you explain where y came from?

Answer (score 0):

In general you would define an UDF like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

// assumption: value is of type double, posttime is timestamp
val myUDF = udf((data:Seq[Row]) => {
  val x: Seq[(Double, Timestamp)] = data.map{case Row(x:Double,y:java.sql.Timestamp) => (x,y)}

  // do something with x 

})
```

The return type of the UDF is given by the type of the last expression. You don't need to create a `Column` within the UDF, just use plain Scala types

Comment: This seems to be something I want. Can we use user defined class for the data type? Can you add more on this function to transform it from collect_List(classA) to class B. Any example of user defined class A and class B will be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your UDF and what you are trying to do. I have modified your login in optimize way. Just check, you are getting expected result or not.

```
val dff = df.union(df2)
  .withWatermark("posttime", "15 minutes")
  .groupBy(window($"posttime", "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),$"id")
  .agg(struct(sum($"value").as("value"), min($"posttime").as("posttime")).as("data"))
```

**or also**

```
val dff = df.union(df2)
  .withWatermark("posttime", "15 minutes")
  .groupBy(window($"posttime", "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),$"id")
  .agg(sum($"value").as("value"), min($"posttime").as("posttime"))
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear code. But my case is not that simple. I just want to aggregate user defined object A to user defined object B with complicated computing process. So system provided agg function sum/min is not able to cover what I want. Here the question is just a simple example.

Comment: Then it's good to start with @raphael-roat's code. You can write your logic inside UDF frame.